# Cannot update MIUI on Redmi S2, "current version is illegal"

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, miui, redmi

I recently bought a second-hand Redmi S2 phone. It was all I got. But the MIUI version was 9.5.1.0, which was very old. That's why I decided to upgrade my MIUI version.

When I tried to update with recovery ROM, it shows

> Can't verify update
>
> Current version is illegal, only allowed to flash the latest stable version

When I tried in fastboot, it says

> Critical Partition Flashing is not allowed

When I tried to unlock the critical partition, it says error. Today, I got a new problem. XiaoMiTool V2 shows my bootloader is locked, but my phone says unlocked.

I don't know what to do. Some experts, please suggest me.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I updated the error messages based on what I found on the internet ([1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mido-cant-update-miui.3662628/), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/critical-partition-flashing-is-not-allowed-on-xiaomi-redmi-4x-help-me.4075431/)). However, if they are incorrect, then please feel free to [edit] and update them with the *exact* error messages for search purpose. Thanks.